# Recovering the Intellij IDEA project after removing .git directory while was checked out in an earlier commit

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I wanted to remove a password from my git history which was in a commit from 2 months ago. Since the project was **not pushed anywhere**, one option was to remove `.git` in the project and then doing a `git init` again. By doing this, I was not aware that the project is in a **checkout to that commit hash from two months ago** and I have removed the `.git` directory carelessly without making a backup of that directory. And according to Murphy's law, no trash, No public/cloud repository, no backup.

I have been trying various recovery applications: *TestDisk*, *EaseUs*, others... but no chance and I believe the data is gone for good; by a kind of zero-writing incident that has occurred at a bad time.

If I could recover my **commit messages** at least, There is chance of rewriting the lost code again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surprisingly I could find the history of file changes in the **right-click context menu -> Local History** on the project root folder and all of my changes are back; even the git history and build folders, and that devil password. In this window nothing needs to be done except doing a right-click on an item in the list and choosing revert. The project is in the exact same state before doing the wring job of removing `.git`.

[image]